# Probability for each of six colors to appear exactly twice after twelve draws with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bowl has six balls that are each a different color. One ball is drawn and then replaced 12 times. What is the probability that each color appears exactly twice?

Comment: Hint: How many words of length $12$ are there such that each of the letters A, B, C, D, E, F appears twice?

Comment: Is it (12! / 2!2!2!2!2!2!)?

Comment: That's right. That will be the numerator. The denominator is easier.